# Как загрузить страницу в кодировке Windows-1251 с помощью HttpClient

Tags: c#, кодировка, httpclient

Ссылка на веб-страницу: http://www.aquatika.ru/prods_rectangular.html

Как видно в `<head>` нам указана кодирока `windows-1251`

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Пытаюсь декодировать так:

```cs
var htm =Client.GetStringAsync(host + collection.QuerySelector("a").GetAttribute("href")).Result;
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

byte[] utf8Bytes = win1251.GetBytes(htm);
byte[] win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, win1251, utf8Bytes);

var document1 = await Program.context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(win1251.GetString(win1251Bytes)));
```

Но выдает в консоли, вместо русских букв:

```
?????????????
```

При наводе на переменную в отладчике так же отображаются вопросы. Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте обработать результат как будто там UTF-8 на самом деле. Бывает, что в `meta http-equiv` указана хрень.

Comment: замените `x.Result` на `await x`

Comment: `curl` выдаёт козябры, а вот `requests` питоновский выдаёт нормальный текст. Мне кажется, что проблема всё-таки именно в неправильной кодировке в `meta`. Хотя странно, что браузеры при этом показывают нормально страницу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там помимо мета-заголовка есть еще HTTP заголовок в ответе от сервера, который собственно и играет ключевую роль в данном вопросе

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
```

По умолчанию для неподдерживаемых кодировок `HttpClient` при попытке загрузить веб-страницу выдает исключение:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The character set provided in ContentType is invalid.
Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.
```

Чтобы это вылечить, при старте приложения (один раз) выполните:

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Оно зарегистрирует кодовые страницы Windows, как это происходит в старом .NET Framework. Тогда `windows-1251` будет распознана HTTP клиентом автоматически.

Вот тестовый пример:

```cs
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.aquatika.ru/prods_rectangular.html");
            
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("title").InnerText);
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Прямоугольные акриловые ванны 150-190х70-120
```

И никаких плясок с бубном вокруг кодировок не потребуется, `HttpClient` все сделает сам.

Comment: Теперь у меня html с русскими буквами, а при парсинге то же самое. Может быть проблема с anglesharp?

Comment: @АлексейНавальный возможно вы где-то еще пошатали кодировки. Например при выводе в консоль, может `AngleSharp` считывает мету и ожидает увидеть данные в кодировке 1251, а они уже перекодированы. Я не работал с этой библиотекой, поэтому могу только гадать.

Comment: @АлексейНавальный попробуйте перед закидыванием в парсер чисто ради эксперимента `htm = htm.Replace("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1251\">", "")`, но это так, наугад, вряд-ли поможет.

Comment: Ахахах, помогло, спасибо

Comment: @АлексейНавальный погуглил, вместо `BrowsingContext` попробуйте так `var parser = new HtmlParser(); var document = parser.Parse(htm);`, без всяких `OpenAsync`. Тогда возможно не придется выпиливать мету.